# Convert time to integer in Php

Tags: php

How would you convert time to integer?

```
 string(8) "04:04:07"
```

I want this as 4(hours) or much better 4.04(4hours and 4 minutes)

I tried

```
  $yourdatetime = "04:04:07";
  $timestamp = strtotime($yourdatetime);
```

Which results in

```
 int(1458590887)
```

Comment: have you tried `date('H', strtotime($yourdatetime));`.... `H` is a military format for date.. and you can try `i` for minutes.

Comment: @SamTengWong I think he wants to represent the length, not convert it into a unix timestamp

Comment: @Machavity but he/she is trying to convert that string to `4hrs and 4mins = 4.04`.. in his /her example... can be achieve using `date('H.i', $timestamp)`

Comment: 4 minutes is not the same as 4 hundredths of an hour.  Your dot delimited time expression is a misleading format.  @Dan

Answer (score 11):

The [date](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) function is your friend:

Given your own code above:

```
$yourdatetime = "04:04:07";
$timestamp = strtotime($yourdatetime);
```

You can then feed it into the date function:

```
echo 'Hours:' . date('h', $timestamp);  // Hours: 04
echo 'Minutes:' . date('i', $timestamp); // Minutes: 04
echo 'Seconds:' . date('s', $timestamp); // Seconds: 07
```

Refer to [the docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) for the specific format(s) you'd like for hours - there's many options.

You could even do it in one move:

```
echo date('h.i', $timestamp); // 04.04
```

If you need it truly numeric:

```
echo float(date('h.i', $timestamp)); // 4.04
```

Comment: lowercase h are hour in form 00-12. You should use uppercase H.

Answer (score 2):

Use `(float)` and `preg_replace` to one-line-code conversion:

```
$floatval = (float) preg_replace('/^(\d+):(\d+).+/','\1.\2',$yourdatetime);
```

Answer (score 2):

So we'll break this out. If we cast the hours as an integer and leave the minutes as a string this is a pretty simple conversion

```
$time = explode(':', $yourdatetime);
$hours = (int)$time[0] . '.' . $time[1];
```

Avoids any overhead from regex

Answer (score 2):

`strtotime()` returns the time in seconds since the Unix Epoch. You can then format this using `date()`. Documentation for date: http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

To get the number of hours (4):

```
$timestamp = date("g",strtotime($yourdatetime));
```

To get the number of hours and minutes (4.03):

```
$timestamp = date("g.i",strtotime($yourdatetime));
```